# Grabbing a variable from another js file

Tags: javascript

example :

original file code:

```
var drawMap = function() {
    for(i=0;i<map.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<map[i].length;j++){
            var drawTile= map[i][j];
            var xpos = (i-j)*tileH + mapX;
            var ypos = (i+j)*tileH/2+ mapY;
            ctx.drawImage(tileImg[drawTile],xpos,ypos);
        }
    }   
    return {
        xpos: xpos,
        ypos: ypos
    }
}
```

new code file:

```
var draw = function(ctx) {
    alert(map.drawMap.xpos);
};
```

the value for xpos in the new code file always comes up undefined... help?

Comment: `drawMap` is a function, you have to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be:

```
var draw = function(ctx) {
    alert(map.drawMap().xpos);
};
```

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.